# Integrating AWS device farm with Jira?

Tags: jira, integration, aws-device-farm

I want to integrate my Jira with AWS device farm. Means Jira ticket should be created if the test cases are failed and also capture which test case is failed for device.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is my suggestion applicable to your use case? If not, what was tried already and what are some of the restrictions for the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible with the [Jira API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/) and the [Device Farm API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

There would need to be a script that pulls the results from the runs. Depending on the environment used you can use the result of the [get-run API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_GetRun.html) and the result attribute to determine if a run failed or not.

Then based on that, call the Jira API to create the new issue.

Hth
 James

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)